# display List from json api in React

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

```js
 how to display title, image and Variation_set price in react from this API

GET /api/products/?format=api
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 6,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?format=api&limit=1&offset=1",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/2/?format=api",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "iPhone Cover",
            "image": "/media/products/iphone-cover/iphone-cover-2_8x7c3td.jpg",
            "variation_set": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "title": "Default",
                    "price": "29.99"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}GET /api/products/?format=api
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 6,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?format=api&limit=1&offset=1",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/2/?format=api",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "iPhone Cover",
            "image": "/media/products/iphone-cover/iphone-cover-2_8x7c3td.jpg",
            "variation_set": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "title": "Default",
                    "price": "29.99"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

how to display title, image and Variation_set price in react from this API

GET /api/products/?format=api
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 6,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?format=api&limit=1&offset=1",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/2/?format=api",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "iPhone Cover",
            "image": "/media/products/iphone-cover/iphone-cover-2_8x7c3td.jpg",
            "variation_set": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "title": "Default",
                    "price": "29.99"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}GET /api/products/?format=api
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 6,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?format=api&limit=1&offset=1",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/2/?format=api",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "iPhone Cover",
            "image": "/media/products/iphone-cover/iphone-cover-2_8x7c3td.jpg",
            "variation_set": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "title": "Default",
                    "price": "29.99"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: you have to show us your code and you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would import Axios,then:

```
getPrices() {
    axios.get('/api/products/?format=api', {
    headers:
        'Accept'        : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

    }).then(res => {
        let values = res.results.variation_set.map((item) => {return {
            title   :   item.title
            price   :   item.price
        }});

        this.setState({prices : values})

    })
}
```

Something like this. And you also have to include images.

Comment: Thank you but  I get Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'variation_set' of undefined, can you check my code. https://pastebin.com/0gwQqGRu

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question isn't quite clear to me, but if I'm right you'd like to display some data that you fetched from an API.

**How to fetch data?**

There are a couple of ways to get the data, e.g. by using the built-in *fetch* method in JavaScript, or you can even take a look at *axios*.

I like both of them, but I prefer using the built-in one. That's because you don't have to install it and its related dependencies.

You can read more about *fetch* [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data).

Afterwards, you'll have all the queried data somewhere in a variable. To display the appropriate fields, you can iterate the aforementioned variable.

**Example**

```
fetch('/api/products/?format=api')
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((data) => {
      for (let someKey in data.results) {
         // data.results, because that contains the fields you asked for
         ...
      }
   });
```

I don't know your exact structure, but something similar to the above should solve your problem. That'd be nice if you could attach some screenshots.

Comment: I get Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'variation_set' of undefined, can you check my code. https://pastebin.com/0gwQqGRu

Comment: You should log out the content of the response data inside your axios request. The message says that the *results* field doesn’t exist in the context.